# How to download embroidery design files to iPad

Tags: ipad, filesystem

When I try to download embroidery design files from a website to iPad, the download fails. I would like to know if there's a way we can force Safari (or Google Chrome) to save such files (formats such as .ART, .EXP, .FES etc) to iPad. Thanks.

Comment: When you download these files to your Mac/PC, what application opens them for viewing/printing?

Comment: Do you only want to save the files and then view them from another device (such as a computer), or do you want to actually view them on the iPad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .ART extension files are most likely in a vector graphics format, which *might* be openable in Adobe Illustrator. Within Adobe Illustrator, you can then save the file as in PDF format, which can then be opened on the iPad.

Failing that, the companies which make these files available need to design an iOS app specifically for this purpose.